# Download de imagem VARBINARY

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Tenho imagens salvas em um banco de dados SQL em `varbinary`, gostaria de saber como fazer para trazer ela de volta na minha aplicação e fazer o download para a máquina em algum formato (`.png`, `.jpg`).

Estou programando com o Visual Studio, na linguagem C#.

Segue código do botão que estou usando para fazer o upload e salvar no banco:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string nomeArquivo = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(nomeArquivo);
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            byte[] imagem1 = ms.ToArray();

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-7FBA9V8\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VALIDACAO;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand("insert into solicitacao (imagem1) values (@imagem1)", conn);

            SqlParameter paramimagem1 = new SqlParameter("@imagem1", SqlDbType.Binary);
            paramimagem1.Value = imagem1;

            comand.Parameters.Add(paramimagem1);

            conn.Open();
            comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();


        }

    }
```

Comment: Gabriel, você realizou alguma tentativa? não tem nenhum outro código que seja relevante à sua dúvida, pois o exemplo que voce postou foi como vc gravou a imagem.

Comment: E por sinal... como você vai saber se é um jpg ou png?

Answer (score 1):

Implemente o seguinte método:

```
private static Image GetImage()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-7FBA9V8\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VALIDACAO;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (SqlCommand comand = conn.CreateCommand(@"SELECT TOP 1 imagem1 FROM solicitacao", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        var arrByte = comand.ExecuteScalar() as byte[];

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(arrByte))
        {
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Depois apenas terá que evocá-lo e atribuir o valor retornado à `PictureBox`:

```
pictureBox1.Image = GetImage();
```

---

Informações retiradas do **SOen**:

[Retrieve varbinary(MAX) from SQL Server to byte[] in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724550/retrieve-varbinarymax-from-sql-server-to-byte-in-c-sharp)

[Byte Array to Image Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/byte-array-to-image-conversion)